# dropdown content position problems

Tags: html, css

I have made a dropdown menu using [this W3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp):

```
    <nav>
        <div class="nav_container">
            <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="">About Us <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="">Benefits</a>
                        <a href="">Team</a>
                        <a href="">Partners</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Solutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">How to Buy</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="">Expertise <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="">Case Studies</a>
                        <a href="">Videos</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="">Support <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="">Resources</a>
                        <a href="">FAQ</a>
                        <a href="">Downloads</a>
                        <a href="">License Actication</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="special">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-KzZiKy0DWYsnwMF+X1DvQngQ2/FxF7MF3Ff72XcpuPs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
/* START - Footer */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

html {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

a,
a:hover,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* START - Navigation Bar */
nav {
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: font-size 0.25s ease, top 0.5s ease;
    background-color: rgba(47, 50, 56, 0.6);
    z-index: 1000;
}

nav .nav_container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
}

nav .logo {
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 4.2em;
    background-image: url("../img/logo-white.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

nav ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: display 0.25s linear;
}

nav ul li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: padding 0.25s ease;
    color: #fffaff;
}

nav ul li a {
    padding: 1em;
    display: block;
    transition: color 0.25s ease, text-shadow 0.25s ease;
    text-shadow: 3px 0px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), -3px 0px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 2px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
    -2px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
    0px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

nav ul #special {
    color: #fffaff;
    background-color: #e00024;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-shadow: none;
}

nav ul #special:hover {
    background-color: #901418;
    text-shadow: none;
}

nav .dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

nav .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(47, 50, 56, 0.6);
    /* min-width: 140px; */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

nav .dropdown-content::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 100%; */
    top: -0.5em;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid #757c8c;
    border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
}

nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(47, 50, 56, 0.8);
}

nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
/* END - Navigation Bar */
```

Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/dyYpeYr

I have added an arrow on top of the `dropdown-content`:

```
nav .dropdown-content::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    /* right: 100%; */
    top: -0.5em;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid #757c8c;
    border-right: 0.5em solid transparent;
}
```

The `dropdown-content` element currently starts in the same point as the `dropdown`. I would like for each `dropdown-content` and arrow(`dropdown-content::before`) to be centered in relation to the `dropdown` text.
I can't seem to get it right.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add those to your CSS:

```
nav .dropdown-content {
    left:50%;
    top: 100%;
    transform:translate(-50%,0);
}
nav ul li a {
    position:relative;
}
```

this will fix it.

Comment: Also, `position:relative;` should be set to `nav .dropdownt` because `nav .dropdown` is the direct parent of `nav .dropdown-content`.

Comment: @Jorje12, Great good to know that, this works because you have to make the positioned absolute element to be relative to another one, and you have to set the coordinates for the absolute element and by setting the mentioned coordinates you will center the absolute element against the closest relative one. hope I explained it well